# What is the purpose of the blue folder icon in Windows?

Tags: windows, icons, files-folders

I always have been amazed at the number of icons Windows has in `shell32.dll` and `imageres.dll`. I've noticed that there is a blue folder in `imageres.dll` (shown) and I haven't seen a use of it before in Windows.

[image: Blue folders]

With my research, I've only found questions about the folder compression icon (the arrows--thanks, Google). I'm definitely sure there is some meaningful use for them.

Has anyone seen them used before? I've only used them manually to make certain folders stand out. Does Microsoft have anything to say for them?

Comment: Usually means it is a compressed folder

Comment: @Moab Isn’t that the blue title and arrows?

Comment: @Biswapriyo I used the shortcut icon picker in Explorer, looking in `imageres.dll`. I don’t know the number

Comment: They are apparently imageres.dll,221 - imageres.dll,223 on my system.

Comment: Which OS? Win 7 or 8 or 10?

Comment: @Biswapriyo I’m using Windows 10. Unsure if Windows 7/8/etc. has a similar icon.